# Is there a way to make other elements disappear when hovering over 1 element

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

I am trying to make it so that when I hover over one of the links on my splash page it displays text and the other buttons disappear. Then when you stop hovering over it the elements reappear.

I tring to do it [here](http://noahtarr.com/index.htm)

I don't have anything so far just an idea. I figure you would have to do display none for the other elements but I do not know hwo to display none for other elements when hovering over another one.

Comment: Show us what you've come up with so far.

Comment: You'll basically need JS for something like that. There might be some CSS trick for doing it (depending on how you want it to work) but it's prolly not worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z33kk/8/) is a minor addition to the two excellent answers already stated.

The hover over the upper circle is done with CSS and the lower hover is done with jQuery.

The important points are that "adjacent" in CSS means "after" - you cannot operate on anything before the hovered element in the DOM.

jQuery .hover can be used with two functions - what to do when you go INTO and element, and what to do when you LEAVE an element.

JS

```
$('.lower').hover(
                  function(){
                           $('.upper').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                           },
                  function(){
                           $('.upper').css('visibility', 'visible');
                             });
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is a easy way to start your use of JavaScript with events. Here is a simple mouse over to hide a box with a fade.

## jQuery ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f7hyy/))

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function() {

        var trigger = $('#hover'),
            target = $('#box');

        trigger.hover(function() {

            target.fadeOut('slow');

        });

     });

 </script>
```

## HTML

```
<div id="hover">Hover over me</div>

<div id="box">Temporary Box</div>
```

Here we select a `trigger` (the element we're hovering over) and a target (the element we want to hide) by providing jQuery Selectors to variables. We provide the selectors IDs of the HTML Elements.  Then, when `trigger` is hovered over, we `.fadeOut()` our `target`

### [Learn more about jQuery Here](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Is the function-by-function API documentation really the place to learn jQuery?

Comment: @wavemode Assuming you've learned something about coding from elsewhere before thinking of jQuery, yes, even they point you there themselves. It's how I learned. HTML, CSS, PHP, simple function manuals as I already had basic syntax down from C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you're intent on css, this can work with a bit of effort. The trick is that the element you want to hide is really a child of the element you're hovering over, but you can put the child wherever you want with absolute positioning and left and top:

```html
<!-- example.html -->
<div id="elem">
    <div id="elemtext" class="elemhide">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
/* example.css */
#elem {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
}
.elemhide {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
#elem:hover .elemhide {
    display: none;
}
#elemtext {
    left: someleft;
    top: sometop;
}
```

You'll have a far easier time with a javascript solution, however.